# Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS won't mount External HDD?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, filesystem

When I try to open the disk it would show me this:

```
error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/ unknown error while mounting /dev/sdb1
```

Then when I try this:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

This happens:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1 
Mounting volume... Inode is corrupt (5): Input/output error
Failed to open $Secure: Input/output error
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Inode is corrupt (5): Input/output error
Failed to open $Secure: Input/output error
Remount failed: Input/output error
```

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, sometimes it's not a hardware fault, but something that *ntfsfix* are unable to repair. Happened to me once... I solved plugging on a PC with Windows, repairing, and using again on Linux normally.

Answer (score 1):

An input/output error generally indicates a hardware fault that was not caused by Ubuntu and usually cannot be fixed by Ubuntu.

- Try a different connecting cable. They go bad.
- If that fails, then buy a new hard drive.

I/O errors and other hardware faults sometimes damage the filesystem. The symptom of filesystem damage can be often fixed by Ubuntu tools like `fsck`. However, `fsck` cannot fix faulty hardware causing the damage.